# Zend PDF wordwrap

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework, word-wrap, zend-pdf

I'm having issues with wordwrapping with Zend Framework2 PDF.  I'm retrieving values from a database to write to a PDF template, but for simplicity's sake I just have a variable with a string:

```
$text = "ASDF ASDF ASDF ASDF ASDF ASDF ASDF";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br/>");
$page->drawText($newtext,50,50);
```

All this code is doing is inserting a 
 tag ever 20 characters:

```
ASDF ASDF ASDF ASDF<br/>ASDF ASDF ASDF
```

Any ideas, this can't be a limitation of ZF2 or ZendPDF can it?

Comment: What is it that's not happening? Is the tag not being inserted? Or is the text displaying wrong?

Comment: I want the string to start a new line after 20 characters.  Since I am statically assigning this text to be printed at X,Y coordinates 50,50 I don't want the text to run off the page of the PDF if it exceeds the page width.

Comment: Have you tried using "\n" instead of "<br/>". I don't know if it will work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I've tried both - still getting the same issue.  Not sure why Zend is treating the string differently.

Answer (score 3):

Found some code that helped me solve it.  Instead of trying to 1 drawText event to write a single string on multiple lines, you have to explode the string and loop through the array drawing each item on a line.

```
$line = 225;
$textChunk = wordwrap($text, 70, "\n");
foreach(explode("\n", $textChunk) as $textLine){
  if ($textLine!=='') {
    $page->drawText(strip_tags(ltrim($textLine)), 75, $line, 'UTF-8');
    $line -=12;
  }
}
```